# How to fine tuning again of a bert fined tuned model

Tags: nlp, bert-language-model

I did a fine tuning bert model for text classification using ktrain.
Again i want to do fine tuning this model on another text classification data. How i can do?

Answer (score 0):

See [this FAQ entry](https://github.com/amaiya/ktrain/blob/master/FAQ.md#how-do-i-resume-training-from-a-saved-checkpoint) on resuming training/fine-tuning.